# Excel Multiple Criteria Serach and If Found insert "x"

Tags: excel

I was hoping someone could help me with an excel formula.

I have a long list of Accounting codes that include Stages - ie: Construction Stage 1, Construction Stage 2. Architect Stage 1, Architect Stage 2 etc.

What I would like is when part of the input cell "Construction Stage 1" contains "Stage 1" the column next to automatically fills (for financial reporting). The column next to it with the formula finds Stage 1 and inserts a "1".

This ties into all our reporting and will make life much easier.

I assume it an IF or MATCH formula.

I would appreciate your help. I suppose the part i don't understand is how you look for a match within text in a cell that requests an output in another cell.

Thanks so much in advanced.

Answer (score -1):

Explain more of what you want to achieve, I guess. But try to use the:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Stage 1",A1)
```

Comment: Appreciate your help!